# All combinations of vector and its negatives in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations

How can I find all combinations of a vector and it's negatives in R?

I.E.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

will output

```
(1,2,3,4), (-1,2,3,4), (1,-2,3,4), (1,2,-3,4), (1,2,3,-4), ... , (-1,-2,-3,-4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `do.call` and `expand.grid`:

```
do.call(expand.grid, lapply(x, function(y) c(y, -y)))
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1     1    2    3    4
# 2    -1    2    3    4
# 3     1   -2    3    4
# 4    -1   -2    3    4
# 5     1    2   -3    4
# 6    -1    2   -3    4
# 7     1   -2   -3    4
# 8    -1   -2   -3    4
# 9     1    2    3   -4
# 10   -1    2    3   -4
# 11    1   -2    3   -4
# 12   -1   -2    3   -4
# 13    1    2   -3   -4
# 14   -1    2   -3   -4
# 15    1   -2   -3   -4
# 16   -1   -2   -3   -4
```

The code `lapply(1:4, function(x) c(x, -x))` creates a list of each element of your vector and its negative; in your case this would be `list(c(1, -1), c(2, -2), c(3, -3), c(4, -4))`. Then `do.call` passes each of these list elements as arguments to `expand.grid`, which returns all possible combinations.

A slightly simpler way to get the arguments could be to use `as.data.frame(rbind(x, -x))` instead of `lapply(x, function(y) c(y, -y))`.

Answer (score 7):

Or a variant of @josilber's solution is

```
 expand.grid(Map(c, x, -x))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `library(gtools)`

```
gtools::combinations(8,4, c(-4:-1,1:4))
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  For example one of the outputs of this is `-4   -1 1 4` whereas I don't think there should be duplicates involved

Comment: @Dason your point makes me think the original question is unclear. "All combinations of a vector and its negatives" to me means what I put.

Comment: I agree.  It's not completely clear what's in the `, ..., ` part of the desired output in the question

Comment: @RichardScriven No it's not completely ambiguous but it looks like they basically just want to generate all possibilities for (+/- 1, +/- 2, +/- 3, +/- 4)